# JQUERY, highlight a column if contains numbers in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-tables

I'm struggling in how to make this simple code work: i only want to check the values of every column and see if they are sequential (like 0 to 7 for example), and if so, highlight that column (class = "snaked" ).

So i marked every cell which belongs to the first row (class = "vstarter") and i tried out this :

```
function is_colsnake() {
  ognicella.filter(".vstarter").each(
    function() {
      var cella = $(this);
      var pos = cella.index();
      var colonna = ognicella.filter(":nth-child(" + (pos + 1) + ")")
      var col = [];
      var issnake = false;

      colonna.each(
        function() {
          col.push(parseInt($(this).text()));
        });

      col.each(
        function() {
          var start = parseInt($(this).text()) ;
          var next  = parseInt($(this).next().text()) ;
          var prev  = parseInt($(this).prev().text()) ;
          var ix = $(this).index() ;

          if (ix == 0) {
            if (next == start + 1) {
              issnake = true;
            } else {
              issnake = false;
            }
          } else if (start != prev + 1) {
            issnake = false;
          }
        });

      if (issnake) {
        colonna.each(function() {
          $(this).addClass("snaked");
        })
      } else {
        colonna.each(function() {
          $(this).removeClass("snaked");
        })
      }
    })
};
```

However it isn't working. Would you please help?

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you should declare all your variables with `var`, not just the first variable in each function.

Comment: This can't possibly work: `if (next == start + 1)`. `next` and `start` are jQuery objects, not numbers. I think you want to set these variables to the parsed text of the elements.

Comment: thanks i tried to adjust it but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: FYI, you can replace the last `if` block with `colonna.toggleClass("snaked", issnake)`. jQuery modification functions automatically loop over all the elements in the collection, you don't need `.each()`.

Comment: this wiil be useful to know so thanks once more but, my problem hasn't been solved yet... do you know what's now wrong here?

Comment: Can you add the HTML and make this  a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.